# Complex Differentiability $f(x+iy) =(x^2 - y^2) + i(x^{3} + y^{3})$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> Find all $z = x+iy$ such that $f(x+iy) = (x^2 - y^2) + i(x^{3} + y^{3})$ is complex differentiable at $z$.

I began by computing the partial derivatives of $f$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &= 2x + i3x^2\\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} &= -2y + i3y^2
\end{align*}

They definitely exist everywhere and I think they are continuous everywhere. So we know from the Cauchy-Riemann equations that $f$ will be differentiable when $f_{x}$ = $-if_{y}$. Comparing the real parts of each and the imaginary parts of each this is when
\begin{align*}
2x &= 3y^{2} \\
3x^{2} &= 2y
\end{align*}
The solutions of this system are $(0,0)$ and $(\frac{2}{3},\frac{2}{3})$, so $f$ is complex differentiable at $z = 0$ and $z = \frac{2}{3} + i\frac{2}{3}$.

Is there anything wrong here?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: I think it's fine.